# Best practices for web apps security

Tags: design-patterns, web, web-applications

I have a web app that, upon login, sends the credentials for server validation - and returns back, among other things, a dictionary of permissions for different UI components throghout the app - which is used to enable/disable or show/hide these components in the front-end.

This is, of course, not secure at all - anyone opening a browser's developer tools console can change these settings on the fly.

I posed this as a problem to my team, and was asked to propose a solution. I am hence trying to sum up what I could think of, and would be glad if anyone could add alternatives I am not aware of (specially if this is a best-practice or common standard):

1. Have the server return the full `html` the user is entitled to see.
2. Use encryption to protect server-client exchanges. The UI would decrypt server responses, and display the data accordingly.

What other alternatives are there for this ?

My stack is server side in `C#` (implemented as a `WCF server`) and `DevExtreme` for the UI (`html` + `js` (with some `js` libraries such as `knockout`)).

(this issue happens throughout all the app, in almost all server served data, not only with login authorizations)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the correct site in the SE Network for this, doesn't http://security.stackexchange.com/ fit this type of question better?

Comment: @Roberrrt: may be. Does security exchange deals with design-patterns as well ?

Comment: I'm not that active since my knowledge of security is fairly weak, but your question isn't necessarily a `design-pattern` but more a regular pattern in design, and I do know they apply those principles there as well.

Comment: You may be right and I may need to move it there. Let's way a bit and see if other responses corroborate this. Thanks

Comment: Good luck with your question!

Comment: @Roberrrt I'd rather have good luck with an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is control security on server side. So not disabled  operations for user will not be enabled for frontend.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you create a database in the server, have your application form a sql query, then the server will send back the data linked to the query. **Make sure to sanitize any data coming in.**